# Problem with InstantApps.showInstallPrompt and postInstallIntent. Intent extras lose

Tags: android-instant-apps, android-app-bundle

postInstallIntent lose bundle extras after installation. I create postInstallIntent this way:

```
val intent: Intent?
intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.test.ru/activity/main/"))
intent.setPackage(context.packageName)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
intent?.putExtra(EXTRA_FIRST, data1)
intent?.putExtra(EXTRA_SECOND, data2)
```

Than call it:

```
InstantApps.showInstallPrompt(
                activity,
                intent,
                REQUEST_CODE,
                INSTALL_REFERRER
        )
```

It opens requested activity, but when I try to get data from intent `intent.extras` in installed app the bundle is empty.

What am I doing wrong or it's a problem of showInstallPrompt?

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to pass data from your Instant app to the installed app and this could happen in the following ways as the support from Android documentation:

1. For Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, you can use the Cookie API [sample app](https://github.com/android/app-bundle-samples/tree/main/InstantApps/cookie-api)
2. For Android 7.1 (API level 25) and lower, you can use Storage API
   [sample app](https://github.com/android/app-bundle-samples/tree/main/InstantApps/storage-api)

For more details see these references:

https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle

[How can I restore data from instant app to installed app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275041/how-can-i-restore-data-from-instant-app-to-installed-app)

[How to transfer the shared prefs from Instant app to full app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132152/how-to-transfer-the-shared-prefs-from-instant-app-to-full-app)
[How to store data in android instant app and restore it in installed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456592/how-to-store-data-in-android-instant-app-and-restore-it-in-installed-app)

Now, in my case, I am using the normal function to open the installed version of the app by using the following function

```
private fun showInstallPrompt() {
        val postInstall = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
            .setPackage(packageName)
        InstantApps.showInstallPrompt(this@MainActivity, postInstall, 0, null)
    }
```